# ¿Deben llevar los símbolos º y ª una raya debajo?

Tags: ortografía, letras

Recuerdo que cuando me enseñaron ortografía (hace ya muchos años), los signos º y ª debían llevar una raya debajo. Lo curioso es que hoy en día, y según la fuente de letra que se use, estos símbolos pueden llevar o no la raya. Por ejemplo, el recuadro de texto en el que escribo esto se ve así:

> [image: Texto]

Como veis, en esa fuente de letra sí tienen la raya debajo. Mientras que en el texto final, que usa otra fuente de letra, dicha raya no aparece. Esto da a veces lugar a equivocaciones, como que tiendo a usar el símbolo º (ordinal) en lugar de ° (el símbolo de grado) en algunos textos matemáticos. Para más inri, en mi teclado la tecla que inserta dichos símbolos sí tiene la raya debajo en ambos.

Así pues, ¿qué dice la RAE al respecto? ¿Deben o no llevar la raya debajo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La respuesta se halla en la [Ortografía 2010](http://www.rae.es/recursos/ortografia/ortografia-2010) de la RAE (negritas mías):

> Las letras voladas son aquellas que presentan un cuerpo menor y se sitúan por encima de la línea de escritura, tomando como referente la línea de las astas ascendentes. **Ha sido costumbre tradicional subrayar las letras voladas** en las abreviaturas, hasta el punto de que muchos tipos de letra incluidos en el catálogo de fuentes de los procesadores de textos presentan subrayadas la *a* y la *o* voladas que se insertan directamente desde el teclado del ordenador [...]. **No obstante, este subrayado, aunque no es ortográficamente incorrecto, resulta innecesario**, de modo que, tanto en tipografía como en la edición digital, se tiende a prescindir de él.

[Enlace](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KeWNHpdaiQBmYSLh).

Comment: Entiendo que si "no es ortográficamente incorrecto, resulta innecesario", es que es **correcto, pero innecesario**

Answer (score 1):

A mí siempre me enseñaron mis profesores de lengua española que la rayita no es un capricho, sino la forma de distinguir la indicación de un ordinal, de la indicación de grados de temperatura o geográficos.